# Why _thread doesnt work on the remote server?

Tags: python, django

This code works on my local server, but doesnt work on the hosting. What could be the problem?

```
import _thread

def email_index(*args):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('ki@gmail.com', 'pas')
    try:
        server.sendmail('ki@gmail.com', 'so@gmail.com', body_mes.encode('utf-8'))
        print('ok')
    except:
        print('An error occurred when trying to send an email')
try:
    _thread.start_new_thread( email_index, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
except:
    print ("Error: unable to start thread")
```

Comment: why not start by [printing the exception](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-catch-and-print-exception-messages-in-python)?

Comment: I have the logs only from Apache. The exceptions isn't there.

Comment: I see, you could write or log it to file I suppose.